# How to add an "Open In" button to an iOS 8 Share Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I need to add an `Open in` button to an iOS 8 Share Extension just like the app [Twitshot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitshot/id959316664?mt=8) have done.
You will get the menu if you share a link from `>Safari >Share >Twitshot`.
How can that be done?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a true share extension.

They are simply using a `UIAlertController` with actions. Their actions are title Open In TwitShot App. And when a user taps on it they are just using a custom URL that opens the app : for example to open YouTube it would be :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YouTube://"]];
```

You just need the custom URL scheme for the apps you want to open